# Get location from ip adress in php?

Tags: php

Я задаю этот вопрос, так как нигде не видел ответа на то, почему в меня не подключается API. Мне не нужны подсказки скриптов, как делать коннект( их в интернете и на этом сайте полно), просто у меня на сайт НИ один не подключается, какая техническая ошибка. Если кто -то сталкивался с подобным, что написано внизу, плиз help me out

Всем привет.

Пытаюсь на своем сайте брать Ip address and location каждого входящего на сайт юзера через $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].
Использовал разные сервисы, предоставляющие сторонние APIs   online, регистрировал API keys, втсавлял в запрос, но ни разу ничего не получилось. То вообще ничего не показывает в стране, регионе, городе, то пишет HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request . Cкину код, знающие люди, подскажите, пожалуйста нубу, в чем проблема. В коде увидите разные запросы к разным серверам (они закомментированы), это все мои попытки и все неудачные.

вот код:

```
//$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
//$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/" . $ip));
//$detailscity = $details->city;
//$detailsregion = $details->region;
//$detailscountry = $details->country;
//echo $detailscity .''. $detailsregion .''. $detailscountry;

//$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

//$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.ipdata.co/{$ip}?api-key=ae84d827f95d795aa7588c1be19c8fb85bb317a284b87bcbcc6f2be7"));
//echo $details->region;

//echo $details->city;

//echo $details->country_name;


    $LocationArray = json_decode( file_get_contents('http://ip2location-api.com/api/serializedphp/'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'?key=f73ee5a4860a26d4d8a3255a1e5718e1'), true);
        echo $LocationArray['country']."</br>";
        echo $LocationArray['city']."</br>";
        echo $LocationArray['region']."</br>";
        echo $LocationArray['timezone']."</br>";



$newIP = file_get_contents('https://ip2location-api.com/api/serializedphp/'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'?key=f73ee5a4860a26d4d8a3255a1e5718e1');
echo $newIP;


$res = file_get_contents('https://www.iplocate.io/api/lookup/'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'');
$res = json_decode($res);

echo $res->country; // United States
echo $res->continent; // North America
echo $res->latitude; // 37.751
echo $res->longitude; // -97.822


var_dump($res);
```

Comment: Если `REMOTE_ADDR` пустой, скорее всего будет `HTTP_CLIENT_IP`, если он пустой, то скорее всего будет `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`. На основе этого напишите функцию и все должно работать.

Comment: REMOTE ADDR не пустой, он мне в echo показывает мой айпишник правильно

Comment: Ну это ваш, ip, а у других он может быть не `REMOTE_ADDR`.

Comment: а как мне узнать, какой мне использовать?

Comment: А еще в Казахстане 90% адресов укажут вам город Алматы, уверен еще парочка стран с таким же долбанутым распределением адресов найдется)

Comment: REMOTE ADDR не бывает пустым